# What actual data format does a Bitcoin Core wallet.dat have?

Tags: bitcoin-core, wallet.dat

I'm trying to extract the **transaction log** from a bunch of wallet.dat files. Not private keys.

All I want is to get access to the transaction log stored inside the wallet.dat.

I can't find any mention of what format this ".dat" file actually has.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What do the different .dat files contain?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/853/what-do-the-different-dat-files-contain)

Comment: Your [previous question](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/110004/13866) has an answer which covers CSV export and prevention of rescan.

Answer (score -1):

Try here, it mentions "bitkeys" format.
https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=4448.0

Also, on the following wiki it mentions Berkely DB and that pywallet can manipulate the file (so you should be able to reuse the raw reading from pywallet):
https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Wallet

Comment: That's the format of the dumps created with the `dumpwallet` RPC, not the wallet.dat format itself.